# Problem with SquareWave in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to have a triangulare signal drive a ODE system, using SquareWave[]. Something seems to go wrong though during integration. `Uext'[t]` and `rate SquareWave[rate/(4 umax) t` evaluate to different graphs. What is the problem here? Thanks!

```
    rate = 0.06;
    umax = 0.9;
    sol2 = Flatten[
    Evaluate[{Uext[t], Uext'[t], rate SquareWave[rate/(4 umax) t]} /. 
         NDSolve[
          {
           Uext'[t] == rate SquareWave[rate/(4 umax) t],
           Uext[0] == -umax
          },
          {Uext}, {t, 0, 400}]]];
    Show[
     Plot[Evaluate[{sol2[[2]], sol2[[3]]}], {t, 0, 400}],
     AspectRatio -> 1,
     PlotRange -> Automatic,
     Frame -> True,
     ImageSize -> {500, 500}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although [*Mathematica* version 9 was supposed to be able to handle discontinuities in differential equations better than earlier versions](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/automatic-discontinuity-handling.html), it still doesn't do it automatically in this example. So you have to manually insure it doesn't jump over a whole period of the rectangle wave, by doing something like this:

```
rate = 0.06;
umax = 0.9;
sol2 = Flatten[
   Evaluate[{Uext[t], Uext'[t], rate SquareWave[rate/(4 umax) t]} /. 
     NDSolve[{Uext'[t] == rate SquareWave[rate/(4 umax) t], 
       Uext[0] == -umax}, Uext, {t, 0, 400}, 
      MaxStepSize -> 2 umax/rate, MaxSteps -> Infinity]]];

Show[Plot[Evaluate[Rest@sol2], {t, 0, 400}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> {500, 500}]
```

[image: solution]

I only modified the `NDSolve` command by adding the options `MaxStepSize -> 2 umax/rate, MaxSteps -> Infinity`. The latter is half a period of the `RectangleWave` and should be enough to not jump over the discontinuities, independently of what you choose for `rate` and `umax`.